# node.js express set title

Tags: node.js, express, pug

How do I set the title of a page/route with express and jade?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

simple.jade:

```
!!! 5
 title= title
```

express application:

```
app.get('/simple',function(req,res) {
    res.render('simple',{title='mytitle'});
}
```

Comment: I think the jade should be {title}. What you did doesn't work for me

Comment: I think I put an extra space in, it should be `title= title`

Comment: should it not be {locals: {title='title'}} ?

Comment: {locals: {title='title'}} works, but newer versions interpret any key that isn't an express command as a local

Comment: Detailed info about locals in views is in the Express guide: http://expressjs.com/guide.html#view-rendering

Comment: You probably need to restart your server as well.

Comment: in 2020, its res.render('index', { title: 'Page Title' });

Answer (score 5):

Specifying the page title in the **route** is easiest method.

This example shows the `index.js` file in my `routes` folder.. which is the default set by Express.

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Page Title' });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what I did and it worked for me. The example uses a hypothetical "videos" view that needs a title to be "video gallery", adjust accordingly.

**layout.jade** //This is added by default in express apps

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  body
    block content
```

**videos.jade** //You can create a view such as this

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
```

**app.js** //The file is default but you must add a route like this. And set the title

```
app.get('/videos/', function(req, res){
  res.render('videos', {
    title: 'Video Gallery'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your server (app.js):

```
app.set('title', 'My Site');
```

Comment: How to render this in ejs template? 
title is not defined